# Hosting several websites on wamp with laravel breaks the routes

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I'm currently hosting several applications on a quite out-dated wamp version but that's not really the case. Everything is working fine on that part, besides my laravel application.

My .htaccess in the `www` folder looks like this;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sapdfr.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!sapdfr/websitev3).*)$ /sapdfr/websitev3/public/$1 [NC,L]
```

The thing that's strange, is that the first page is working but when I'm going deeper into the website, it just totally breaks. I've been trying to rewrite these rules but I'm seriously mindblown about all the possibilities. Any help will be greatly appreciated since I'm entirely lost here.

Comment: Where is your public folder?
Are you trying to access your application on your browser like "localhost" or "localhost:8000"?

Comment: I'm actually hosting it on a windows machine, the public folder should be in `sapdfr/websitev3/public` as where my root is where the `.htaccess` is located (www folder, it's on a wamp server). The domain registration has a dns rule to redirect `sapdfr.org` towards the IP of the server, the htaccess is actually redirecting several sites hosted on there.

Comment: have you check that your document root is rightly pointed in apache conf?

Comment: Should be okay, I haven't changed anything there. @Chay22 Should I change something there?

Comment: What does your www folder have to do with your Laravel apps? It sounds like you are mixing up several different things.  You can host as many different vhosts on a single server (WAMP, LAMP, irrelevant) as you want, but they typically would not share any directories or .htaccess files.  Edit your question and clarify what exactly you have, and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a silly question but have you try that ? :)

Laravel includes a `public/.htaccess` file that is used to provide URLs without the `index.php` front controller in the path. Before serving Laravel with Apache, be sure to enable the `mod_rewrite` module so the `.htaccess` file will be honored by the server.

If the `.htaccess` file that ships with Laravel does not work with your Apache installation, try this alternative:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

and then just redirect your domain to the laravel public folder

Comment: The alternative worked, thanks lad. Working with laravel daily but never really duck deep into the .htaccess file inside the public folder.